# fading out wave texture with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

does anyone have an idea how I can create a wavetextur in geometry nodes with a flowing gradient?. I can limit the texture but I always have a sharp edge and no smooth transition. I hope the picture can make that clearer.

many thanks

Julian

[image]

Comment: You already use a Scale node to control the strength of the effect - you can similarly control the strength based on the Z position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  But first, let's identify something you're doing that doesn't make sense: you're turning a fac into a vector via vector math, then turning that vector into a scalar by plugging it into your bottom vector math/scale input.  Your vector math/multiply isn't really serving much purpose here, and you'd be better off using a math/multiply node here, or building that multiplication into your Map Range node (with "clamp" disabled.)

After that, the reason that you always have a sharp edge is because you're either displacing it or you're not, because you are operating via "selection"; and the size of that scale is not at all a function of the Z position of the vertex.

[image]

Here, instead of acting on a selection, I'm acting on *all* vertices, but I'm modulating the displacement down to 0 for most of them.  By remapping the Z position with the Map Range and RGB curves nodes, then scaling my displacement vector by that remapping Z position, I can create a smooth gradient of no displacement (at or above Z = 0.0) to full wave displacement (at or below Z = -0.5).  With just the map range node on Linear, this would be interpolated linearly; the RGB curves node shows how I change that interpolation curve arbitrarily.

Comment: +1.. tiny thing... GN has a _Float Curve_  node.

Comment: @RobinBetts I didn't know that!  But it didn't used to, and it ends up being the same thing, so I'm probably not going to switch :)  I'm still in the habit of using a bunch of RGB stuff where Blender doesn't really support it, or maybe only didn't used to support it, like mixRGB to do any kind of lerp3, color or vector.

Comment: Zackerly. No need to edit ... FYI only.